# call "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method on webview.goBack()

Tags: android, webview, history

I'm loading all my pages inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method on `webview` (mainly to track the current page url and do some modifications).

My problem is that the back button ( eg: `webview.goback()` method ) bypasses the above function.

Is there any way i can explicitly call both the `goback()` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` methods.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
//get current url and do some modifications to html}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
         webview.goBack();  
         return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code seems like once the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is called based on some logic for a specific URL Action you need the `Webview` go back method. I would suggest you to use the following method inside the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

which does exactly the same as onKeypressed. (Used `onBackPressed` instead of `onKeypressed` but write this code inside the Activity class but not inside the custom `WebViewClient`.

Call the `onBackPressed()` inside your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. Try this, should work.